# Bluemix "forbidden" error on JSP pages

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I deployed my java application on Bluemix. It's a Spring MVC application with some REST controller to expose web services and some jsp page to create a admin panel.
The JSP pages are in the root of web application (not in WEB-INF directory). If I run the application in local on my tomcat server, everything works, the web services and the JSP, but if I deploy on Bluemix i have this error:

```
Error 403: SRVE0190E: File not found: /admin/index.jsp
```

It's a strange error because it says "File not found", but it's not a 404 error, but a 403 (Forbidden), so I think it could be some kind of configuration problem...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application runs on tomcat locally, then you can try using the tomcat buildpack:

`cf push <appname> -b java_buildpack -p path/to/file.war`

Answer (score 0):

your problem seems related to your application context root, probably the server.xml resulting after application uploading and staging is not enough to manage it.

Generally speaking before submitting an application on Bluemix it should be better trying to deploy it to a local Liberty server first. If you are able run this application locally on your liberty server, package up the server, and then push the package using the related option from cf cli.

Follow this link https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html
to have a complete reference about java liberty runtime on Bluemix and about its options